# How to make user verify password again (Just Password)?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

How can I make my user verify password whenever they want to change their bio.

Or simple can anyone please tell me how too extract the password for self.request.user like User.password or something.

I'm writing this from my mobile phone and 
I've very simple model so I think no one would need code for it

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
self.request.user.check_password(request.POST['reset_password'])
```

Check the doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password

Django never stores the raw password, something like `user.password` will give you a hashed version of the password that you can't reverse. That's why you need to hash the one that comes from the user input and compare the hashed version. `check_password` will do just that for you.

More info on how Django manages passwords: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/